# SQL How do you find missing ID's (not in sequence, or without sequence)?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data in a table that looks like the picture below.  Each DocID, has a number of ItemID's associated with it.  I am trying to find which DocID's don't have an ItemID of '14000' for example (bottom right of the picture.)

How can I get a list of all DocID's that don't have an ItemID of '14000' associated with it, please?

[image]

Here is one version of what I've tried so far.

```
SELECT      
d.DocID
FROM            tableD AS d
WHERE           d.GID = 19
            AND d.TID = 159
            AND 1283 NOT IN (SELECT d.ItemID FROM tableD)
GROUP BY    d.DocID
```

Here is a temp table in case it's helpful.

```
CREATE TABLE #t1 (
DocID   int
,GID    int
,TID    int
,ItemID     int
,Keyword VARCHAR(40)
)

INSERT INTO #t1 
VALUES 
(321654,    28, 1789,   13841,  'Jim'),
(321654,    28, 1789,   13851,  'Smith'),
(321654,    28, 1789,   13861,  'William'),
(321654,    28, 1789,   13871,  '000-00-0000'),
(321654,    28, 1789,   13881,  'SALARY'),
(978312,    28, 1789,   13841,  'Jim'),
(978312,    28, 1789,   13851,  'Smith'),
(978312,    28, 1789,   13861,  'William'),
(978312,    28, 1789,   13871,  '000-00-0000'),
(978312,    28, 1789,   13881,  'SALARY')
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please don't use images for data, use formatted text.

Comment: You made things *harder* , not easier. Images can't be copied, queried, compiled or executed

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I see your point, I added a temp table in case it's helpful.  Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `HAVING`:

```
SELECT d.DocID   
FROM tableD AS d
WHERE  d.GID = 19 AND d.TID = 159
GROUP BY d.DocID
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN itemid = '14000' THEN 1 END) = 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!  For others, and it helps me learn to try to explain it, thanks to Gordon's explanation, the HAVING clause is assigning a 1 to any docid that has the itemID of 14000, and a 0 to any docid's that don't.  Then it further filters the list to show only those with a 0, which means any docid that doesn't have a 14000 associated with it.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to find which DocID's don't have an ItemID of '14000' for example (bottom right of the picture.)

You can use aggregation with a `having` clause:

```
select docid
from tableD
group by docid
having sum(case when itemId = 14000 then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

This code counts the number of items that you care about.  The having clause says none of those items are associated with a given `docid`.

I'm not sure what your code has to do with the question you asked.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff!!  I kept the where clause in there for my code.

Comment: Would you mind explaining exaclty what your having clause is doing?

Comment: Thanks for your help and your explanation!  My desired result required using the code with the where clause.

Comment: @JM1 . . . You can of course keep any filtering you want in the `WHERE` clause.  That filtering is not part of the question you asked.